# How do I install ADOBE Flash Player?

Tags: flash

How do I install ADOBE's **Flash Player** (32-bit version) ?

When I try to do this, logged-on as the current user, the following error message is displayed:

> *You must have administrative privileges to install ADOBE flash Player*.
>   *Please log on with administrative privileges and try again*.

When I then log-on with administrative privileges as instructed, and try again to install, I still get the *same* error message.

Examining my **Windows 7** 64-bit system, I get the above error message at each setting of **Integrity Level** for the Macromedia directory (and the Temp directory), both *low* and *medium*.

When I try to uninstall the existing version of Flash Player, prior to retrying the install (which is an attempt to upgrade to the current release), the uninstall fails.

Can you suggest any reason why this particular error message might be being displayed? Are there known factors which trigger this specific error?

Comment: **(1)** Why installing 32-bit Flash Player on 64-bit system? Does it fail with 64-bit Flash Player? **(2)** Did you try right-click and choose "Run As Administrator"? **(3)** You ae installing the Stand-Alone Flash Player, right? _eg:_ The EXE file includes an `SA` in the name (for "Stand Alone" version)? Otherwise for some Win 7 browsers (Chrome, MS Edge) it's already built-in and cannot be installed.

Comment: Both 32-bit and 64-bit installers fail in an identical manner; and using the option 'Run As Administrator' makes no difference to this outcome. Both the web installer and the stand-alone installer fail in an identical manner. I am running Firefox on Windows 7, and the existing flash player (updated many times over the years) works, but all my attempts to update it once more do not succeed (even though the stand alone versions of the plugin updater always performed successful updates in the past).